Select rows with same item code but different value in another column

I have data from 2 tables. Item and Location are from table A and Description from Table B. Im trying to write an Oracle SQL where I am able to obtain those items and locs where the description in Loc 1 is different from all the other Locs for the same item but show me rows with Loc 1 and Loc 2 only.
I tried getting the full list and then a export to excel and then finding duplicates etc but that list is so long that the export fn does not work and so does copy-paste into excel as well.
The end game here is that I need to update the Loc 1 description with what is there in the Loc 2 rows.
Therefore here is what I aim to achieve with this SQL.


Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the CREATE TABLE  and INSERT statements for your sample data (a text we can copy-paste and execute and not images). At the moment, from your description, there does not appear to be any referential constraints between the two tables if table A contains only two columns item and location and table B only contains a single column description so there is no way to join the two tables; you need to have a primary key and then join based on that.

Thanks MTO. i will edit the tables as you suggested asap as soon as soon as I get the hang of doing it. About the SQL itself, thanks for your input but two points. Both the tables are joined by yet another column let's call it 'Item_Identifier' common to both of them which is 1-1 so Ive joined them on that. However when I run the SQL, I get an error pointing to the very last line of the code. ORA-00904: "LOCATION": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier" *Cause:    *Action:

................COUNT(DISTINCT description) OVER (PARTITION BY item) AS num_descr
FROM  ItemTable A join ItemDescriptionTable B on A.Item_Identifier = B. Item_Identifier
)
WHERE  num_descr = 2..........

Hi MTO, Yes this has worked for me as well too. i had to tweak the code a bit of course but yes it worked. All three SQLs below were different approaches but I got yours to work as well. Thanks for your help and effort.

You can use conditional aggregation with analytic functions:
SELECT item,
       location,
       description
FROM   (
  SELECT item,
         location,
         description,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE location WHEN 'Loc 1' THEN description ELSE NULL END) OVER (
           PARTITION BY item
         ) AS num_loc1,
         COUNT(DISTINCT CASE location WHEN 'Loc 1' THEN NULL ELSE description END) OVER (
           PARTITION BY item
         ) AS num_other_loc,
         COUNT(DISTINCT description) OVER (PARTITION BY item) AS num_descr
  FROM   a
         INNER JOIN b
         ON a.item_id = b.item_id
)
WHERE  num_descr > 1
AND    num_loc1 = 1
AND    num_other_loc + num_loc1 = num_descr
AND    location IN ('Loc 1', 'Loc 2')

or, depending on how you want to implement the logic of "where the description in Loc 1 is different from all the other Locs for the same item", you can change the final filter to:
WHERE  num_descr > 1
AND    num_loc1 = 1
AND    num_other_loc + num_loc1 = num_descr
AND    location IN ('Loc 1', 'Loc 2')

Which, for the sample data:
CREATE TABLE a (item_id, item, location) AS
SELECT  1, 'Item A', 'Loc 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  2, 'Item A', 'Loc 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  3, 'Item A', 'Loc 3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  4, 'Item A', 'Loc 4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  5, 'Item B', 'Loc 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  6, 'Item B', 'Loc 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  7, 'Item B', 'Loc 3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  8, 'Item B', 'Loc 4' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT  9, 'Item C', 'Loc 1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Item C', 'Loc 2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'Item C', 'Loc 3' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'Item C', 'Loc 4' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE b (item_id, description) AS
SELECT 1, 'Tube' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Pipe' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Pipe' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Pipe' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'Mallet' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'Mallet' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'Mallet' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'Mallet' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'Wrench' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'Spanner' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'Spanner' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'Spanner' FROM DUAL;

Both output:



ITEM
LOCATION
DESCRIPTION




Item A
Loc 1
Tube


Item A
Loc 2
Pipe


Item C
Loc 1
Wrench


Item C
Loc 2
Spanner



fiddle

Another way to solve this is by using a case staetement and the exists operator
but you also need a unique identifier of the 2 tables (a, b)
with all_data as (
select a.*, b.description from a join b on a.item_id=b.item_id
), flag as (
select a.* , case when exists ( 
                               select * from all_data where item=a.item and a.location <location and a.description <> description)
                                                                                                             
              then 1 else 0 end as flag
from all_data a
), grp as (
select a.*, sum(flag)over(partition by item order by location)as grp, 
            row_number()over(partition by item order by location)as rn_loc
from flag a 
)
select item, location, description
from grp
where grp=1 and rn_loc<3;

Hope it helps.

Thanks Florin. I will be trying your suggestions in the next couple of days and will provide feedback.

Please do.Thank you

Hi Florin, Yes this has worked for me. i had to tweak the code a bit of course but yes it worked. Thanks. Same for the other two suggestions. Thanks again.

If you already have a query which results as in the start of the question...
-- lets imagine this is your query
      Select      A.ITEM, A.LOCATION, B.DESCRIPTION
      From        A
      Inner Join  B ON ( /* your join condition(s) */ )
      Order By    A.ITEM, A.LOCATION
/*
ITEM    LOCATION    DESCRIPTION
------  ----------  -------------
Item A  Loc 1       Tube
Item A  Loc 2       Pipe
Item A  Loc 3       Pipe
Item A  Loc 4       Pipe
Item B  Loc 1       Mallet
Item B  Loc 2       Mallet
Item B  Loc 3       Mallet
Item B  Loc 4       Mallet
Item C  Loc 1       Wrench
Item C  Loc 2       Spanner
Item C  Loc 3       Spanner
Item C  Loc 4       Spanner
Item C  Loc 5       Spanner
Item C  Loc 6       Spanner
Item C  Loc 7       Spanner       */

... then you could declare its sql as a cte (named  it all_data) and using just that cte get your result ...
WITH
  all_data AS      -- Your query's sql declared as cte named all_data
    ( Select      A.ITEM, A.LOCATION, B.DESCRIPTION
      From        A
      Inner Join  B ON ( /* your join condition(s) */ )
      Order By    A.ITEM, A.LOCATION
   )
--    M a i n    S Q L :
Select      a.ITEM, a.LOCATION, a.DESCRIPTION 
From        all_data a
Inner Join  ( Select  ITEM, DESCRIPTION
              From all_data
              Group By  ITEM, DESCRIPTION
              Having    Count(Distinct LOCATION) = 1 
            ) g ON( ( g.ITEM = a.ITEM And g.DESCRIPTION = a.DESCRIPTION And a.LOCATION = 'Loc 1') 
                      OR
                       ( g.ITEM = a.ITEM And g.DESCRIPTION != a.DESCRIPTION And a.LOCATION = 'Loc 2') 
                    )

... the subquery in main sql will fetch just items having unique Loc 1 description per item and Join's ON conditions should filter the final result which should be ...
/*    R e s u l t :
ITEM    LOCATION    DESCRIPTION
------  ----------  -------------
Item A  Loc 1       Tube
Item A  Loc 2       Pipe
Item C  Loc 1       Wrench
Item C  Loc 2       Spanner    */


Thanks d r. I will be trying your suggestions in the next couple of days and will provide feedback.

Hi d r, Yes this has worked for me as well. i had to tweak the code a bit of course but yes it worked. Thanks

@redoctober If that is ok - you could consider upvoting all usefull and accepting one of the answers that fits your needs the best.

Done. Thanks again d r. Appreciate the help and effort.

@redoctober Good choice, thanks.
